# SQLite WHERE-Clause for every column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Does SQLite offer a way to search every column of a table for a searchkey?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE ...
```

Selects all rows where `...` was found in the column `id`. But instead to only search in the column `id`, I want to search in every column if the searchstring was found. I believe this does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * LIKE ...
```

Is that possible? Or what would be the next easy way?

I use Python 3 to query the SQLite database. Should I go the route to search through the dictionary after the query was executed and data returned?

Comment: Have you looked at the full text options? http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Not really.  In general, you need to name each column you search.  However, you might be interested in a full text index, if you are searching for text in lots of columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple trick you can do is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ((col1+col2+col3+col4) LIKE '%something%')
```

This will select the record if any of these 4 columns contain the word "something".

Comment: But every column must be entered manually, correct? Or is there a way to simply automatically select all columns? I don't think a subselect would be possible.

Comment: is there a trick to get this running? I'm not getting a result using this..
```
SELECT *
FROM personen
WHERE ((vorname+nachname) LIKE '%David%')
```

Comment: @nuts: which RDBMS are you using? Your query seems fine if it is not case sensitive.

Comment: @RagingBull it's regular SQlite3 and it's not case sensitive. It's okay though, I handled it differently. Thanks though :)

Comment: Can anyone explain what does the "+" do in this context? i.e. how exactly does it work? I can't find documentation for this anywhere online.

Comment: @Divyansh, "+" will basically concatenate the values from those columns into a single value. Examples here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat_with_plus.asp

Answer (score 2):

I could not comment on [@raging-bull answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732523). So I had to write a new one. My problem was, that I have columns with `null` values and got no results because the "search string" was `null`.

[Using coalesce](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/) I could solve that problem. Here sqlite chooses the column content, or if it is `null` an empty string (""). So there is an actual search string available.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (coalesce(col1,"") || coalesce(col2,"") || coalesce(col3,"") || coalesce(col4,"")) LIKE '%something%')
```

Answer (score 1):

No; you would have to list or concatenate every column in the query, or reorganize your database so that you have fewer columns.

SQLite has [full-text search tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) where you can search all columns at once, but such tables do not work efficiently with any other queries.

Comment: According to the docs the functionality for FTS tables is not enabled by default and requires recompiling the binaries.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure, if I understood your question. 
If you want the whole row returned, when id=searchkey, then:

```
select * from table where id=searchkey;
```

If you want to have specific columns from the row with the correct searchkey:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table where id=searchkey;
```

If you want to search multiple columns for the "id": First narrow down which columns this could be found in - you don't want to search the whole table! Then:

```
select * from table where col1=searchkey or col2=searchkey or col3=searchkey;
```