# SQLite searching database for user input using the LIKE operator

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am trying to find a way to search through a database by using the input from a textbox, but I can't seem to figure out how to formulate the query.

What is supposed to happen:
User enters in a string into the text box and clicks the search button.
The button click event fires, and runs a SQL query that takes that input and returns the rows where it matches or contains.

I wanted to use something like (using parameters of course):

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE DeviceName LIKE '@SearchBox';
```

However, this limits it to just the `DeviceName` column. Which means they can't search for a term that is not in the `DeviceName` column. If they wanted to search by a date, or device type, or the asset tag, or whatever then this SQL statement obviously wouldn't work.

I was also thinking of having the user specify the search parameters via a drop down box (i.e. Search by Name, Asset Tag, Date, etc.) And then depending on their selection, running the proper SQL statement using the appropriate column name in the `WHERE` clause. But that seems like a bunch of extra work that can be avoided.

I did read some previous question that seemed to involve creating another index table, but i'm not sure if that would be the best way to go.

Thanks!

Edit:
Tried the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ((col1+col2+col3+col4) LIKE '%something%')
```

as posted in [SQLite WHERE-Clause for every column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732480/sqlite-where-clause-for-every-column)

query executes but doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite WHERE-Clause for every column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732480/sqlite-where-clause-for-every-column)

Comment: @OlivierRogier The query in the answer to the question you posted executes, but doesn't return any rows. I tested it on a different table using a term that I verified was in several of the rows. Posted solution: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((col1+col2+col3+col4) LIKE '%something%')`

Comment: Did you replace colX by your columns and `%something%` by `%@SearchBox%` fro example ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes. I did find that using `WHERE ((col1 || col2 || col3 || etc.) LIKE '%something%'` Seemed to work, but doesn't return any rows if some of the columns are NULL. (I'm using sample code on here for simplicity, and testing on the SQLite DB Browser before putting it into my code)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that using

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE ((col1 || col2 || col3 || etc.) LIKE '%something%;
```

Works. However, I had to set a default value of `' '`(a blank space so it's not null) on the columns so it will return every relevant row, even if there is no values entered into a cell. If it was NULL it would skip those rows (which is why it wasn't returning anything).